# Align TextField Inputs in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I'm using a `Form` to create some TextFields, but I'm wondering **how to align the input fields** (notice the "Required" placeholders do not have the same leading alignment).

**The code**

```
NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Full Name")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        TextField("Required", text: $companyName)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("JobTitle")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        TextField("Required", text: $companyName)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Title"))
        }
```

**The Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a "hack" that will align these both as if they both said "Full Name". The second "full name" is hidden.

```swift
NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Full Name")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        TextField("Required", text: $companyName)
                    }
                    HStack {
ZStack{
Text("Full Name")
.fontWeight(.semibold)
.hidden() // <-- HERE! This will fix alignment but hide text
                        Text("JobTitle")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
}
                        TextField("Required", text: $companyName)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Title"))
        }
```

This will make `SwiftUI` align it correctly but still show the text. Another option is the `.offset` modifier (docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(x:y:)).